# How To "Cancel" AVAudioSession on segue to another view controller?

Tags: ios, avaudiosession, avaudiorecorder, swift4.2

I'm creating an Audio Recording application with a Tab Bar Controller. I've created a RecordingView using AVAudioRecorder with proper session and URL that passes the recording to another view controller using a segue identifier.

The issue I'm having is handling if the user were to switch tab bar views before completing the recording session. Ideally, I'd like to cancel the session so that when they come back to the Recording View everything is like new. [Here is the code I used to pass the URL to another view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dtQb.png)

I've considered just opening the recorder in a view without a tab bar so that the user would have to use a cancel button to leave the view, but this is a good learning experience. I know this is a simple fix but for some reason I can't figure it out. Thanks in advance for any and all assistance :D

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55128493/edit) to include your code as text and not as an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop the recording in `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear` method in your `RecordingViewController`. These methods will be called when user selects another tab.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    // Stop your recording session here.
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew this couldn't have been a hard fix. Your help is much appreciated.